# Low php5-fpm performance after deployment / changing php files

Tags: php, nginx, symlink, fpm, google-compute-engine

we are running nginx + php5-fpm and as part of our deployment process we use a symlink to point to the latest version of our PHP code. 
In order to avoid problems with changing files when deploying new versions, we use the following nginx-config, which uses $realpath_root to send the real file path to php-fpm:

```
location ~* ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

This setup worked well for the last year while we used AWS instances. Now we switched to Google Cloud and every time we deploy a new version, our servers response time increases by factor 2-3.
After reloading PHP-fpm using `kill -USR2 17` (where 17 is the process ID of the master process), response times recover to normal values.

[image: Increased response time after deploy]

Any suggestions how to solve this without restarting php-fpm worker processes after every release?

Best,
Tobias

Comment: have you gone through new relic slow transactions?

Comment: It's not a specific transaction with high response times. Simply all transactions are slower than before.

Comment: Have you solved this? Same with php7.4